Why does the commented C code skip user input when called from another function?
The function with the problem
void login_starts()
{
    while (TRUE)
    {
        memset(username, 0, USERNAME_MAX_SIZE*sizeof(char));



        HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN);


                /* THE PROBLEM IS THE LINE BELOW */

        printf("Username: "); fgets(username, USERNAME_MAX_SIZE, stdin);
        newline_remover(username);
        


        if ((strlen(username)<USERNAME_MIN_SIZE)||(strlen(username)>USERNAME_MAX_SIZE))
        {
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED);

            printf("Username must be between 3 to 32 characters!\n\n");

            continue;
        }



        else {check_account_existence();}



        fclose(fptr);

        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_BLUE);
    }
}

When this function is called from the marked part with comment, only then input is skipped.
The function from where it is called, block is marked
void check_account_existence()
{
    memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(char));

    snprintf(buffer, sizeof(buffer), "users\\%s.dgw", username);

    fptr = fopen(buffer, "r");



    if (fptr==NULL)
    {
        HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED);

        printf("Username doesn't exist!\n\n");


        SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_GREEN);

        printf("Want to open a new account? (y/n): ");
        scanf("%c", &decision); printf("%c", '\n');



        if (decision=='y')
        {
            memset(buffer, 0, BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(char));
            strappend(buffer, &buffer_pos, "users\\");
            strappend(buffer, &buffer_pos, username);
            strappend(buffer, &buffer_pos, ".dgw");
            memset((buffer + buffer_pos), 0, (BUFFER_SIZE*sizeof(char) - buffer_pos));

            password_setting();
        }



        /* PROBLEM OCCURS WHEN CALLED FROM THIS else if BLOCK BELOW */

        else if (decision=='n') {login_starts();}



        else
        {
            HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, FOREGROUND_RED);

            printf("Unknown command received!");
            login_starts();
        }
    }



    else {logging_in();}
}

What I have tried:

Using C++ input functions like getline(cin, str).
gets() [Though unsafe].
Tried removing newline too, but still nothing changes.

More about question:

How is it possible that user input skipped?
Is it a function issue? Or is it a unexpected behavior due to some other reason?
How can I avoid it?

Expectation:

The input function always stops for user input than being passing an empty string itself.


You know where it fails, simply set a breakpoint after those lines and check what you got in the input buffer?

This is hardly a [mcve], and we don't know what your input looks like (or is expected). Please read How do I ask a good question?. Also, this code is badly structured and in need of refactoring, which may help you identify the problem. Also, are you using C or C++? They are very different languages. This code is clearly C, but you mention trying getline(cin, str), which implies you are using a C++ compiler in C mode.

@Biffen Kindly stop making 100% subjective coding style preference changes to posts. That's considered vandalism. Fixing indention is a valid edit. Adding spaces, brace style etc according to personal preference is not.

The previous scanf() call consumes the character assigned to decision leaving the newline in the buffer.  The newline then satisfies the fgets() call without further input.

@Lundin I have tried adding breakpoints and printing functions where I felt doubtful, but the point is how can a program skip user input, which must waits for user's prompt?

@RemyLebeau Yes, but that's why commented the problem part. Providing whole function may provide more context to possible problem.

@Clifford Wait, then how to avoid that? Is it by flushing stdin or something else?

@InfiniteIntuitions Simplest fix is to change scanf("%c", &decision); to scanf("%c", &decision); getchar();

Thanks a lot to @Clifford for helping me, it did work. Plus I added space before %c and than used getchar(), it was a newline in stdin buffer issue which had to be consumed/flushed.

Thanks a lot to @Lundin for helping me, it did work. Plus I added space before %c and than used getchar(), it was a newline in stdin buffer issue which had to be consumed/flushed.

Flushing stdin is implementation defined (and critically works in Microsoft but not gnu libraries).  The question is a duplicate, the duplicate has an answer so I'd did not feel the need to elaborate. The issue is with scanf not fgets there are hundreds of questions already on SO that duplicate this.  It is a very common gotcha.

Note that the getchar() solution will fail if you enter say "yes" rather than "y" or just enter a blank line.  You might do better to: while( decision != '\n' && (c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF ) ; if you want a robust line discard.  The EOF is required if stdin can be redirected from a file (and on anything with any kind of operating system, it can).
